# highlight current line of word document when move up or down

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wanted to develop a program such a way that when up or down arrow moved, highlight the entire line of text. So when I go up or down with arrow keys it highlight the line where my cursor is.

So I developed this code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentPosition As Range
Set currentPosition = Selection.Range 'pick up current cursor position

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight


currentPosition.Select 'return cursor to original position

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.EndOf

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Then I tried to assign this macro to both Up arrow key and Down arrow key. Then I realised that we can't assign one macro for 2 key combinations. So I created 2 macros like this. (Content is same. Only name is different.).
And assigned SelectLineUp to Up arrow key and assigned SelectLineDown to down arrow key.

```
Sub SelectLineUp()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentPosition As Range
Set currentPosition = Selection.Range 'pick up current cursor position

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight


currentPosition.Select 'return cursor to original position

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.EndOf


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

And this is for down arrow

```
Sub SelectLineDown()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentPosition As Range
Set currentPosition = Selection.Range 'pick up current cursor position

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight


currentPosition.Select 'return cursor to original position

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.EndOf

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Now the problem is when I press down arrow in the keybord it works as I intended. But when I press Up arrow, it still goes down dirrenction in the document. Highly appreciate if you can tell me what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. I used some additional methods for changing the Selection (or Range) locations, such as `MoveEnd`, `MoveStart` and `Collapse`. Note the change for the highlight setting of the entire document, so that you don't have to change the Selection.

If you use F8 to step through the code, and switch between the VBA Editor and document windows, you can see how these methods work. The details can be found in the VBA Help.

```
Sub SelectLineUp()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveDocument.content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

    Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, -1
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'Unselect the line
    Application.Selection.StartOf
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SelectLineDown()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveDocument.content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

    Selection.MoveStart wdLine, 1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'Unselect the line
    Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This works for me, while keeping the code very DRY.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nKey As Long) As Integer

Public Sub KeyUpOrDown()
    Dim keyUp As Boolean
    keyUp = CBool(GetKeyState(vbKeyUp) And &H80) ' Was "keyup" pressed

    If (keyUp) Then
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine
        Call HighlightLine
    Else
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
        Call HighlightLine
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub HighlightLine()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim currPosition As Range
    Set currPosition = Selection.Range

    ActiveDocument.Content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.Expand Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    currPosition.Select

End Sub
```

Both trigger keys can be bounded to the public subroutine "*KeyUpOrDown*".

I like the way this works, because it has a native feel. As you hinted in your code, the selection point does not get collapsed to one side but it maintains it's original position while switching line.

Another big one is the simulated key press event using the external "*user32.dll*" library.

I hope you'd find it useful.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about this part of the code. {Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nKey As Long) As Integer   }   can't we modify it to {  (Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user64.dll" (ByVal nKey As Long) As Integer }      to work with 64bit?

Comment: And is there a good website or youtube video to learn about {Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nKey As Long) As Integer} liek things?

Comment: @coderH Replacing the Declare statement with this: `Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer` would work on both 64bit and 32

Comment: You can check out this [webpage](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) to learn more about 64bit & 32bit compatibility. But to learn more about the "Declare statement" you can google this keyword "Declare statement in VBA". I would advice that you read blog posts before checking into MSDN. Do check out this [cpearson post](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Bitness.aspx) too. Cpearson is generally a good website to learn advanced VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A little performance improvement in the accepted answer. Un highlighting whole document takes too much time if you have 400 pages book. 
Also the code doesn't return you to same cursor position.
I have modified the code a little bit to solve both issues:
Add this to declaration section.

```
Dim currSelection As Range
```

bind these macros to up and down keys

```
Sub UpKey()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'get current position
    Dim currPosition As Range
    Set currPosition = Selection.Range

    'remove highlight from previous line
    If Not currSelection Is Nothing Then
        currSelection.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End If
        
    'move and highlight new line
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Set currSelection = Selection.Range
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'get back to old spot and move the line
    currPosition.Select
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub DownKey()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim currPosition As Range
    Set currPosition = Selection.Range

    If Not currSelection Is Nothing Then
        currSelection.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    End If
        
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Set currSelection = Selection.Range
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    currPosition.Select
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Note:** If for some reason a row stays highlighted then take cursor to the row and move up or down once.