# Highlight current word when press right or left arrow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to develop a program in such a way that when right or left arrow is pressed the current word is highlighted. So when I go left or right with an arrow key the word where my cursor is is highlighted. Part of this I was able to develop with the information in
[highlight current line of word document when move up or down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982327/highlight-current-line-of-word-document-when-move-up-or-down)

For right arrow I currently have:

```
Sub SelectWordRight()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveDocument.Content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

Selection.MoveStart wdWord, 1
Application.Selection.Words(1).Select

Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and for left arrow

```
Sub SelectWordLeft()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

Selection.MoveEnd wdWord, -1

Application.Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.StartOf
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works really well. But when there is word with bounding charaters like open bracket and close bracket then it highlights only the bracket.

For example consider this - I like this website (stackoverflow)

When I press one of the arrows it works for other words. but when it comes to (stackoverflow) it highlights (, stackoverflow and ) seperately. So is there way I can highlight words seperated by spaces?

With the help of Cindy's answer I was able to develop a solution for left arrow like this.

```
Sub SelectWordLeft()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

Selection.MoveEnd wdWord, -1

Selection.MoveStartUntil " ", wdBackward
Selection.MoveEndUntil " ", wdForward
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Unselect the line
Application.Selection.StartOf
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But still I was unable to figure out how to convert this to use in right arrow. It fails when there are characters like - : ) ( { }

Comment: This is an interesting question. Note that your revised `SelectWordLeft` would not work with something like "Stackoverflow.com is a great website." - i.e. when the text starts with a "complex" word and no preceding space - but probably a minor detail. I'm just curious to see the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the right arrow, please do check it out.

```
Sub SelectWordRight()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveDocument.Content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

MoveToStartOfANewWord:      ' I added this label also

    Selection.MoveStart wdWord, 1

    ' I Added this BLOCK over here
    '-----------------------------
    ' PURPOSE: Move to the start of a -
    ' word i.e. our definition of a word

    'Debug.Print "'" & Selection.Previous & "'" & _
                " - " & Asc(Selection.Previous)
    If (Asc(Selection.Previous) = 32) Or _
        (Asc(Selection.Previous) = 13) _
    Then
        'check 4 "space" then "paragraph"
        GoTo ItIsAtTheStartOfANewWord
    Else
        GoTo MoveToStartOfANewWord
    End If

ItIsAtTheStartOfANewWord:


    Application.Selection.Words(1).Select

    ' I Added this BLOCK over here
    '-----------------------------
    ' PURPOSE: To extend the selection
    ' till the begining of a new word

ExtendTillStartOfANewWord:

    'Debug.Print "'" & Selection.Characters.Last & "'" & _
                " - " & Asc(Selection.Characters.Last)
    If (Asc(Selection.Characters.Last) = 32) Or _
       (Asc(Selection.Characters.Last) = 13) _
    Then
        'Selection.MoveEndUntil Cset:=" "
        GoTo SelectionIsAtTheStartOfANewWord
    Else
        Selection.MoveEnd wdWord, 1
        GoTo ExtendTillStartOfANewWord
    End If

SelectionIsAtTheStartOfANewWord:


    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'Unselect the line
    Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It's looks quite much but it works quite well, **especially over paragraph break**. I hope you can modify it for the left arrow.

Comment: OMG. It worked perfectly. Thank you very very much for putting this much effort to solve this issue.

Comment: I am glad you found it useful. If you encounter any challenge in making it work for the left arrow, I would glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one macro - it's possible to assign one macro to multiple keys.

The proposed approach uses the `MoveStartUntil` and `MoveEndUntil` methods to extend the Range (or Selection) until a specified set of characters (in this case a space) is encountered.

```
Sub SelectWord()
    Dim rng As Word.Range    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveDocument.content.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Set rng = Selection.Range 
    rng.MoveStartUntil " ", wdBackward
    rng.MoveEndUntil " ", wdForward

    rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'Unselect the line
    rng.Select
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. But it didn't work for me. My cursor stuck when I press arrows. However with the directions given in your post, I was able to develop solution for left arrow. I have edited the question with that solution. But still I was unable to convert it to right arrow.

Comment: @coderH I don't understand why you can't assign the same macro to both left and right arrows? If the cursor is in a word it shouldn't matter which is pressed?

Comment: Yes I found a way to assign both left and right arrows to macro. And then I did it for the macro written by you. But it didn't work for me. Because it seems like cursor stuck in highlighted word. It doesn't move. However thank you very much for your help. It showed me a direction to solve left arrow my self.